# Android CLI build shows invalid resource directory name error: MY_PROJECT\res/crunch

Tags: android, cordova, build

I'm building my ***PhoneGap*** Android app using the *Node.js* command line interface, with the command `phonegap run android`. It shows this error:

```
-code-gen: 
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one. 
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\brian.lee\Desktop\Eclipse
Workspace\facebook_trial\plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect\src\android\facebook\FacebookLib\res/crunch    
BUILD FAILED
```

I first assumed that it was just looking for a missing folder, so I created a `crunch` folder under `MY_PROJECT/res`, to no avail. I also tried using Eclipse to perform a Project->Clean, to no avail.

**How do I fix this error? Why is it happening? Also, why is it showing opposing slashes in `.\res/crunch`? Does that matter?**

**EDIT:**

Eclipse Luna has been showing this error now, as well:

> [2014-05-21 11:15:37 - Facebook_Trial] invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\brian.lee\Desktop\Eclipse Workspace\facebook_trial\plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect\src\android\facebook\FacebookLib\res/crunch

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Close Eclipse and then run `ant clean` in your project folder.